# Opening new pop up GUI window from exisiting plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have built a plugin named ABTD plugin.

I am planning to add a button to the plugin named "centroid connectors" , and when we click on that button, a new pop up window dialog box will appear with the GUI.

This is my plugin with the button `centroidconnector` :

[image: plugin with button]

Then I made these new files in the existing ABTD folder, i.e `cc.ui`, `centroidconnectors_dialog.py` in `CentroidConnectors` folder.

[image: project files inside visual studio code]

Now I want to import these files in my `ABTD.py`.

So I wrote :

```py
from .CentroidConnectors import *
def cc_dialog(self):
        cc1 = CentroidConnectors_dialog(self.iface)
        cc1.show()
        cc1.exec_()
.
.
.
# In run method :
self.dlg.cc_btn.clicked.connect(self.cc_dialog)
```

Also it gave me an error saying `" module not callable"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CentroidConnectors_dialog` is a module(a .py file), you cannot call it. You have to call, for example, a class in that file, like:

```
from .CentroidConnectors import *

def cc_dialog(self):
    #                               vv This is the class in py file
    cc1 = CentroidConnectors_dialog.CentroidConnectors()
    cc1.show()
    cc1.exec_()
```

or

```
#                                                         vv This is the class in py file
from .CentroidConnectors.CentroidConnectors_dialog import CentroidConnectors

def cc_dialog(self):
    cc1 = CentroidConnectors()
    cc1.show()
    cc1.exec_()
```